# Android AsyncTask downloading .mp3 file - info and thumbnail

Tags: java, android, android-asynctask, download, mp3

I am trying to download a mp3 file from a server. 
I successfully made it, and I can play the file, but there is no thumbnail and file info, such as artist and album names.

When I'm downloading the file directly from chrome, the information I stated above, DOES get downloaded.
Any ideas how to get it work?

Here is my code:

```
            URL url = new URL(urlDwn+urlVid);

            HttpURLConnection connection =(HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
            connection.connect();

            //file length
            int lengthOfFile = connection.getContentLength();
            //intput - read file
            InputStream inputStream = new BufferedInputStream(url.openStream(), 8192);

            //output - write file
            if(true) {
                System.out.println("Downloading");
                OutputStream outputStream = new FileOutputStream(root+"/"+fileName); 
                System.out.println(root+"/"+fileName);
                byte data[] = new byte[1024];
                long total = 0;
                while ((count = inputStream.read(data)) != -1) {
                    total += count;
                    //progress
                    publishProgress((int) ((total * 100) / lengthOfFile));

                    //writing to file
                    outputStream.write(data,0, count);
                }
                outputStream.flush();
                outputStream.close();
                inputStream.close();
```

Comment: maybe the problem the way you are retrieving the thumbnail and info?

Comment: How can I retrieve it?

Comment: you do retrieve it some way when you download it via chrome.

Comment: But I dont want to use chrome for that. Im writing data to the file that i created, and the audio works well. But I dont understand why the thumbs and info of the file not working.

Comment: where exactly they are not working?

Comment: When Im downloading the file using the code i wrote, I can see in file manager that no thumbnail or artist and album info is available. (unknown artist). But when im using chrome to download the file from the url, it is available.

Comment: try copying the downloaded file to the PC and inspecting it on the PC. Also check the file size - if it is equal to the chrome-downloaded file size. What I think about is that you need to trigger someting like *Hei, Android system, here is new file I've just created. Please scan it, and record the artist and thumbnail information in your database*, and only after that the file manager will be able to extract this info. I think chrome does this way.

Answer (score 1):

I SOLVED IT!

it seems that the thumbnail and mp3 tag(artist and etc) were downloaded properly. the problem was in the file manager itself(or maybe the Android system), so when I restarted the device, it shown itself!

EDIT

There is no need to reboot. All you need to do is to add the lines below to the *onPostExecute* method, which tell the system that a new file has been added.

```
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MEDIA_SCANNER_SCAN_FILE);
intent.setData(Uri.fromFile(file));
sendBroadcast(intent);
```